# Implementing a Conditional-GET

Tags: java, rest, http, get

I Have a RESTful web service created using Java connected to a db containing cars and implamenting CRUD operations and testing using Postman.

Currently it just uses the conventional HTTP GET returning status 200ok when a car in the database is returned successfully.

I am trying now to implement a conditional GET to return status 304 when a second GET request is submitted and the entity has not been modified from the previous GET request.

Reading about the conditional GET i know it uses the Last-modified and if-modified-since headers but struggling on how to go about implementing this.

Within the db i have a trigger to update a TIMESTAMP associated with each entity after they have been modified and i presume this will be the value that will be checked to see if the entity has been modified since the last request ?

Any Help appreciated

The Current GET request:

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("{reg}")
public Response getOneCar(@PathParam("reg") String reg) {

    Car car = dao.getCarDetails(reg);
    System.out.println("GET CarReg == "+reg);

    if(car == null){ // no car with that reg exists
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
                .entity("<carNotFound reg='"+reg+"' />")
                .build();
    }else{   

        car.setLink(new ArrayList<Link>());

        Link linkSelf = new Link();
        linkSelf.setRel("self");
        linkSelf.setUri(context.getPath());

        Link deleteLink = new Link();
        deleteLink.setRel("/linkrels/car/delete");
        deleteLink.setUri(context.getPath());

        Link updateLink = new Link();
        updateLink.setRel("/linkrels/car/update");
        updateLink.setUri(context.getPath());


        car.getLink().add(linkSelf);
        car.getLink().add(deleteLink);
        car.getLink().add(updateLink);


        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.OK)
                .entity(car)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Example of one of the entities:

```
<car>
    <id>3</id>
    <regNo>03G333</regNo>
    <make>Ford</make>
    <model>Focus</model>
    <link rel="self" uri="cars/03G333"/>
    <link rel="/linkrels/car/delete" uri="cars/03G333"/>
    <link rel="/linkrels/car/update" uri="cars/03G333"/>
    <time>2018-03-23 10:00:05.772</time>
</car>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response @Andrew,

I am currently trying to do this using the "If-Modified-Since" and "Last-Modified" Headers.

On The server i am sending a "Last-Modified" Header to the client which takes the timestamp from the current car in the db as shown in the image --> [postman server responce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIVp9.png)

Now i am trying to configure postman to send back the "if-Modified-Since" header.

if i compare these values and depending on the timestamp being the same or different i can determine the response to be sent back.

currently having trouble configuring postman to send the "If-Modified-Since" Header and then taking this value in on the Server somehow.

```
  Date date = null;

        try {

          SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
          String lastmodifiedDate = car.getTime();               
          date = sdf.parse(lastmodifiedDate);

        } catch (ParseException ex) {

        } 

          return Response
                .status(Response.Status.OK).lastModified(date) 
                .entity(car)
                .build();

    }
}
```

Comment: I have misread the initial question, my response was irrelevant.